# Using lambda function in code pipeline without internet gateway

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to use a lambda function inside a code pipeline that has no internet gateway. I am using `boto3` to invoke `put_job_success/failure_result` on my code pipeline. It was working when I had an internet gateway in my environment but it was since removed because of security risks. Now that the internet gateway is gone my lambda function hangs for 20 mins after calling put_job_success_result and eventually fails. Neither `put_job_success_result` or `put-job_failure_result` are working anymore. Does anyone know what I have to do to get my lambda to communicate with my code pipeline without an internet gateway?

The code pipeline (generated via CFT) does not have a private endpoint. I tried adding one manually but that didn't seem to work either.

```
# Pipeline def
pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')

# success function
def put_job_success(job):
    # Notify code pipeline of successful job
    logger.info('Job Success ID = {}', job)
    logger.info('Putting job success')
    pipeline.put_job_success_result(jobId=job)

# job_id assignment
job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']

# call to success function
put_job_success(job_id)
```

I was expecting that once the function is done and success result is put that the codepipeline would reflect that. It used to before I took out the internet gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use "VPC Endpoints" to access AWS services without an Internet Gateway and/or NAT: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html#use-vpc-endpoints-with-codepipeline

This will present the AWS service on your VPC. You will need to put your Lambda function in the same VPC as your new AWS Endpoint - perhaps this was the bit that wasn't done before?

(I'd be surprised if the timeout is 20 minutes. The max timeout for a Lambda is 15 minutes but boto should timeout at 60 seconds.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The lambda was already in the correct VPC, however the code pipeline was not. When I added the vpce for the code pipeline manually I used the wrong security group. Using the right security group yielded that little green check mark I love so much.

Thank you!